# Unity - How to combine sprites into one

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, sprite, tile

I want to make RPG game using Unity2d with the tile feature to draw the game map.

I created a new class inherited from `UnityEngine.Tilemaps.Tile` and overrided `void GetTileData`.

In `void GetTileData` I determine the **sprite to show for each tile** according to the tile's neighbors.

See the image below. The source image is input from the inspector. The input is **only one image** like this below. I don't want to make massive input images caus that totally mess up.

But then I have a problem. When in the game I have to extract certain blocks from the source image and combine them into a new sprite to show onto the map as a tile sprite.

[image]

> **Just want to know, if I have the 4 rectangles known, and want to combine them into a sprite like the image above, how can I do that?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy way to do what you want in code. Simply use a tilemap with smaller base tiles.

Comment: I searched lots of relatives and you concluded my problem. I found a fantastic plugin to help me make those small tiles